# Shiny Switch on Input from Radio Buttons Causes Error About Reactive Context

Tags: shiny

I'm trying to access the value of a radio button in shiny outside of a render function, but it always returns an error about a reactive context. Why do I need to have a reactive context to access the value of it, shouldn't I be able to see it in the shiny server function?

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("dist", "Distribution type:",
                   c("Normal" = "norm",
                     "Uniform" = "unif",
                     "Log-normal" = "lnorm",
                     "Exponential" = "exp"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      textOutput('dirtText')
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  # This causes the reactive error
  d <- switch(input$dist,
           norm = {print('duck1')},
           unif = {print('duck2')},
           lnorm = {print('duck3')},
           exp = {print('duck4')},
           {print('goose')})
  }
  # should now be a function pointer to one of the code blocks.

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # Yet this does not
    dist <- switch(input$dist,
                   norm = rnorm,
                   unif = runif,
                   lnorm = rlnorm,
                   exp = rexp,
                   rnorm)

    print(input$dist)

    hist(dist(500))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The reactive error is as follows.

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5181
Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Stack trace (innermost first):
    46: .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext
    45: .subset2(x, "impl")$get
    44: $.reactivevalues
    43: $ [/home/hschmale/wildfig/new_dashboard/switch_reactive_not_working/app.R#37]
    42: server [/home/hschmale/wildfig/new_dashboard/switch_reactive_not_working/app.R#37]
     1: runApp
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in the error message you need to include your switch statement inside a reactive, like:

```
d <- reactive(switch(input$dist,
       norm = {print('duck1')},
       unif = {print('duck2')},
       lnorm = {print('duck3')},
       exp = {print('duck4')},
       {print('goose')}))
```

This is because `input$dist` is not defined when you first run the `server` function, it is only defined in a `renderXXX` or in any other `reactive` function

### Edit

But for this to work, you need to use `d()` somewhere, for example you call it in the `renderPlot`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  d <- reactive(switch(input$dist,
                       norm = rnorm,
                       unif = runif,
                       lnorm = rlnorm,
                       exp = rexp,
                       rnorm))
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({hist(d()(500))})
}
```

Comment: I tried the same but inside of a code blocks in `reactive({ ... })`  and it didn't work, but is there something special about reactive with code blocks. My understanding is that you're defining an anonymous function.